# Passing an array of variables FROM an object

Tags: php, forms, class

So here's what I want to do, I have a class and within `SomeClass`, there's a function consists of 2 variables, each has a numerical value.  I want to return an array of the two variables which have dependencies in post data outside of `SomeClass` from a form that posts to itself.

```
<?php 
class SomeClass{

    private $someVar1;
    private $someVar2;

    public function setVars($var1,$var2) {  
       $this->someVar1 = $var1;
       $this->someVar2 = $var2;
    }

    function __construct() { 

    }

    function setFraction() {
          $sum['num'] = 140*pow($this->someVar1,0.75);
          $sum['den'] = $sum['num']/$this->someVar2;
          return $sum;
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['num'])){$num = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $_POST['num']);}
elseif(isset($_POST['den'])){$den = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $_POST['den']);}
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">

  Numerator:<input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($num)){echo $num;}?>" name="num" /><br />

  Denominator:<input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($den)){echo $den;}?>" name="den" /><br />

  <input type="submit" value="Go" name="Go"> 

</form>

<?php if(isset($num,$den)):
  $obj = new SomeClass();
  $obj->setVars($num,$den);
  $sum=$obj->setFraction();?>

  <pre>
    <?php print_r($obj->setFraction());?> 
  </pre>

  <ul>
    <?php foreach($sum as $val):?>
      <li><?php echo $val['num']?></li>
      <li><?php echo $val['den']?></li>
    <?php endforeach;?>
  </ul>

<?php endif;?>
```

When I run the script, post data for `$num` and `$den` is being sent and returned with `setFraction()`, however when I try to iterate through the array in a foreach loop, I don't get any return data.  I'm sure its something simple, I've tried it with a foreach loop and without with same results, any help would be excellent, thx.

**EDIT:**

```
<?php if(isset($num,$den)):
  $obj = new SomeClass();
  $obj->setVars($num,$den);
  $array = $obj->setFraction();?>

  <ul>
    <li><?php echo $array['num']?></li>
    <li><?php echo $array['den']?></li>
  </ul>

<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: you haven't assign `$sum=$obj->setFraction();` to `$sum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the returned data  to some variable,and then iterate.

//

```
<?php if(isset($num,$den)):
  $obj = new SomeClass();
  $obj->setVars($num,$den);
  $array = $obj->setFraction();?>


  <ul>
    <?php foreach($array as $val):?>
      <li><?php echo $val['num']?></li>
      <li><?php echo $val['den']?></li>
    <?php endforeach;?>
  </ul>

<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Thank you! This answer was the closest one. I used `echo $array['num'];` instead of with a foreach loop and it works!

Answer (score 1):

auYou're not assigning the return values of `$obj->setFraction()` to a variable. You need to do:

```
$sum=$obj->setFraction();
```

and all should be OK.

Just becuase you're returning a variable called `$sum` doesn't mean that that variable name is used once it's back in the main body of your script.

I have just noticed, as you rightly state in your acceptance, that you don't need the `foreach` block. Just use `$sum['num']` and `$sum['den']`. Sorry about that - I should have noticed earlier

Answer (score 1):

you haven't assign `$sum=$obj->setFraction();` to $sum

Answer (score -1):

You should use $obj->sum instead of $sum.